# How can I get the revert reason of a call in Solidity so that I can use it in the same on-chain transaction?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, contract-design, revert-opcode

I want to get the revert reason of a failed `call` and then use that revert reason in the same on-chain transaction. Is this possible?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I modified shanes answer:

```
function _getRevertMsg(bytes memory _returnData) internal pure returns (string memory) {
    // If the _res length is less than 68, then the transaction failed silently (without a revert message)
    if (_returnData.length < 68) return 'Transaction reverted silently';

    assembly {
        // Slice the sighash.
        _returnData := add(_returnData, 0x04)
    }
    return abi.decode(_returnData, (string)); // All that remains is the revert string
}
```

It seems to work and that way we dont need the extra library

Comment: Uniswap used your code. Wanted you to know. https://github.com/Uniswap/uniswap-v3-periphery/blob/v1.0.0/contracts/base/Multicall.sol

Answer (score 9):

Yes, this is possible. In short, you can use the following code:

```
(bool success, bytes memory res) = _destination.call.gas(_gasLimit).value(_value)(_data);

// Get the revert message of the call and revert with it if the call failed
if (!success) {
    string memory _revertMsg = _getRevertMsg(res);
}
```

```
/// @dev Get the revert message from a call
/// @notice This is needed in order to get the human-readable revert message from a call
/// @param _res Response of the call
/// @return Revert message string
function _getRevertMsg(bytes memory _res) internal pure returns (string memory) {
    // If the _res length is less than 68, then the transaction failed silently (without a revert message)
    if (_res.length < 68) return 'Transaction reverted silently';
    bytes memory revertData = _res.slice(4, _res.length - 4); // Remove the selector which is the first 4 bytes
    return abi.decode(revertData, (string)); // All that remains is the revert string
}
```

---

Breaking that down a little, all unsuccessful calls will return an erroneous response with the signature `Error(string)` (0x08c379a). With that in mind, you can simply treat it as any other signature.

`if (_res.length < 68) return 'Transaction reverted silently';`

The above line will look at the response and return `Transaction reverted silently` if there was no revert reason.

`bytes memory revertData = _res.slice(4, _res.length - 4);`

The above line will derive the revert reason `string` from the response in the format `bytes` format. As a note, the `slice` method is from [this BytesLib.sol](https://github.com/GNSPS/solidity-bytes-utils/blob/master/contracts/BytesLib.sol) file.

`return abi.decode(revertData, (string));`

The above line will decode the data into a string, which is the desired output.

*Note: For full disclsure, I am a cofounder of Authereum and those code blocks are from the [Authereum contracts](https://github.com/authereum/contracts/blob/master/contracts/account/BaseAccount.sol#L116-L125) that I helped write.*

Comment: Thanks for the explination. 
Where does 68 come from? 64 bytes + 4 for the signature? Why at a minimum will a revert lead to more than 64 bytes of data?

Comment: I would also like to know understand this.

Comment: That's because of the way dynamic data is encoded. ABI for solidity reverts is `Error(string)`, so the first 4 bytes will be selector, next 32 bytes will be string offset, next 32 bytes will be string length and all the remaining bytes will be string data. See https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/abi-spec.html#use-of-dynamic-types

Answer (score 7):

While the answer from @Paddy looks correct, it screws up the length of `_returnData` before passing it to `abi.decode`.  The screwed up length is much bigger than it should be.  Hopefully `abi.decode` will just ignore extra bytes after the decoded string, but it would be better not to rely on this, so here is cleaner version:

```
function extractRevertReason (bytes memory revertData)
internal pure returns (string memory reason) {
    uint l = revertData.length;
    if (l < 68) return "";
    uint t;
    assembly {
        revertData := add (revertData, 4)
        t := mload (revertData) // Save the content of the length slot
        mstore (revertData, sub (l, 4)) // Set proper length
    }
    reason = abi.decode (revertData, (string));
    assembly {
        mstore (revertData, t) // Restore the content of the length slot
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If only interested in bubbling up the revert then could do:

```
(success, returnData) = _target.call{value: _value}(_data);
if (!success) {
    assembly {
        revert(add(returnData, 32), returnData)
    }
}
```

Assembly's `revert` takes the memory location of the beginning of the revert data and its length. `returnData` points to the beginning of `bytes memory` which starts with a length prefix 32 bytes long. After that prefix the actual revert data follows.

Answer (score 1):

There are many cases of reverts:

- `Panic(uint256)` (Defined since 0.8.0, see https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/control-structures.html#panic-via-assert-and-error-via-require)
- `Error(string)` (Defined at least since 0.7.0)
- Custom errors (Defined since 0.8.0)
- And other cases including revert without reason

A generic way to bubble up the error can be:

```
// Taken from https://github.com/superfluid-finance/protocol-monorepo/blob/dev/packages/ethereum-contracts/contracts/libs/CallUtils.sol

    /// @dev Bubble up the revert from the returnedData (supports Panic, Error & Custom Errors)
    /// @notice This is needed in order to provide some human-readable revert message from a call
    /// @param returnedData Response of the call
    function revertFromReturnedData(bytes memory returnedData) internal pure {
        if (returnedData.length < 4) {
            // case 1: catch all
            revert("CallUtils: target revert()");
        } else {
            bytes4 errorSelector;
            assembly {
                errorSelector := mload(add(returnedData, 0x20))
            }
            if (errorSelector == bytes4(0x4e487b71) /* `seth sig "Panic(uint256)"` */) {
                // case 2: Panic(uint256) (Defined since 0.8.0)
                // solhint-disable-next-line max-line-length
                // ref: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/control-structures.html#panic-via-assert-and-error-via-require)
                string memory reason = "CallUtils: target panicked: 0x__";
                uint errorCode;
                assembly {
                    errorCode := mload(add(returnedData, 0x24))
                    let reasonWord := mload(add(reason, 0x20))
                    // [0..9] is converted to ['0'..'9']
                    // [0xa..0xf] is not correctly converted to ['a'..'f']
                    // but since panic code doesn't have those cases, we will ignore them for now!
                    let e1 := add(and(errorCode, 0xf), 0x30)
                    let e2 := shl(8, add(shr(4, and(errorCode, 0xf0)), 0x30))
                    reasonWord := or(
                        and(reasonWord, 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff0000),
                        or(e2, e1))
                    mstore(add(reason, 0x20), reasonWord)
                }
                revert(reason);
            } else {
                // case 3: Error(string) (Defined at least since 0.7.0)
                // case 4: Custom errors (Defined since 0.8.0)
                uint len = returnedData.length;
                assembly {
                    revert(add(returnedData, 32), len)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```